# The site I created fails LCP on mobile only. I don't get a score, only "?"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lottie, pagespeed-insights

I created a [site](https://bliq.tech/) for a client. The desktop score is good, but the mobile measurements [results in an error](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbliq.tech%2F&tab=mobile). Is this a bug with PageSpeed Insights? Very frustrating since it will impact the sites performance in Google. Can I fix this myself somehow? I don't want to remove the animation but I have a feeling that it's the animation that is causing issues. The animations are rendered with lottie-web using the react-lottie npm package.

Comment: Lighthouse sometimes fails when you have animations as openers. 

What happens is that there is no Largest Contentful Paint recorded in the performance trace and this is where it gets its information for for that audit. Without that the whole scoring system fails. Not much you can do unfortunately as nobody seems to have found (last time I checked) the root cause of the performance trace failing to pick up the LCP, technically a Chromium bug rather than a Lighthouse one.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thank you for your reply. This is interesting, I'm going to contact my client and explain the problem and then perhaps remove the animations on mobile... frustrating. I also noticed that "Preconnect to required origins" errors out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out and it's so dumb. Lighthouse doesn't recognize that I have any content on the site because the content is too far down, or something like that. So I put a <p> tag in the top. This is DUMB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).